# Subscribe not working angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I am new to angular 2 and I am trying to get data from a service.The problem is data is not displayed and the services component does not show up in the network tab under chrome developer tools

This is my **Service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http,Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { DCSComponent } from '../dcs/dcs.component';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class ServicesService {

   constructor(private http:Http) { }

   extractdata(res:Response) {
     return <DCSComponent[]>res.json();
   }

   getdata():Observable<DCSComponent[]> {
      return this.http.get('http://localhost:53158/api/Test').map(this.extractdata);
   }
}
```

And this is the **component subscribing to the service** ,

```
import { Component, Input,OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ServicesService } from '../services/services.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dcs',
  templateUrl: './dcs.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dcs.component.css'],
  providers: [ServicesService]
})

 export class DCSComponent implements OnInit  {
   data: any[];

   constructor(private servicesService : ServicesService){ }

   ngOnInit(){
    this.servicesService.getdata().subscribe(data=>this.data=data);
   }
}
```

**app module** just in case

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule,CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { AlertModule} from 'ng2-bootstrap';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { DCSComponent } from './dcs/dcs.component';
import { HCMComponent } from './hcm/hcm.component';
import { FinanceComponent } from './finance/finance.component';
import { EmployeeComponent } from './employee/employee.component';
import { HelperComponent } from './helper/helper.component';
import { TravelRequestComponent } from './dcs/travel-request/travel-request.component';
import {RouterModule} from '@angular/router';

import { ServicesService } from './services/services.service';
import { DataComponent } from './data/data.component'
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    DCSComponent,
    HCMComponent,
    FinanceComponent,
    EmployeeComponent,
    HelperComponent,
    HelperComponent,
    TravelRequestComponent,
    TravelRequestComponent,
    DataComponent,     
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
        [AlertModule.forRoot()],
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      {path:'CreateRequest',component:TravelRequestComponent},
      {path:'welcome',component:HelperComponent},
      {path:'',redirectTo:'welcome',pathMatch:'full'}
    ])
  ],
  providers: [ServicesService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**Network tab:**

[image]

Comment: **what error you are getting??** Welcome to Stackoverflow have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before asking a quesiton.

Comment: "not working" is no information. Please explain clearly what the problem, the actual and expected behavior is.

Comment: Hi sorry for the lazy question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest its highly useless to have a **extractdata()** method when you are going to use it as below which works in just one line.

```
getdata():Observable<DCSComponent[]>
{
  return this.http.get('http://localhost:53158/api/Test')
                  .map((res: Response) => <DCSComponent[]>res.json());
}
```

However to fix your problem you should be using this way

```
getdata():Observable<DCSComponent[]>
    {
      return this.http.get('http://localhost:53158/api/Test')
                      .map((response: Response) => this.extractdata(response));
    }
```

As solved through remote teamviewer, following are the mistakes which you made

1. HelperComponent should not be the component during routing as in app.module
2. You are having the services in the DCS component so you need to initiated.
3. that  Null error was because selector was null and so that error from zone.js
4. data: any[]; is decalared but not defined. so I it in the constructor.

Comment: yes i have done the changes.But my problem is that data is not retrived from the server.ANd the server is runnning

Comment: no i dont have a team viewer what is it exactly? and the data is retrived from a controller which i have created

Comment: if it is here too much of conversations will keep going. if you are not comfortable lets continue the discussion in a chat which I will create here. which is fine for you?

Comment: a chat here would be better

Comment: I am not getting any error but the data is not been retrived from the server

Comment: i.e whe i scroll to the netwrk tab in google chrme the services component does not pop up....which it should if the call is processed correctly

Comment: this means that there is something wrong you are doing. did you correct the code as per my suggestion?